# Why does my AngularJS template loader work with version 1.6.1, but not with 1.7 (or 1.8)?

Tags: angularjs, factory, angularjs-ng-include, ng-template

I'm looking for a way to load ng-templates from a bundled html file to use as src in ng-include.

I found a demo that exactly suited me needs, and is working fine in AngularJS 1.6.1. Unfortunately in the newer versions 1.7 and higher it no longer works.

```js
    var app = angular.module("test", []);
    app.factory("$templateCache", function($cacheFactory, $http, $injector) {
      var cache = $cacheFactory("templates");
      var allTplPromise;
      return {
        get: function(url) {
          var fromCache = cache.get(url);
          if (fromCache) {
            return fromCache;
          }
          if (!allTplPromise) {
            allTplPromise = $http
              .get("all-templates.html")
              .then(function(response) {
                $injector.get("$compile")(response.data);
                console.log(response.data);
                return response;
              });
          }
          return allTplPromise.then(function(response) {
            var result = {
              status: response.status,
              data: cache.get(url),
              headers: response.headers
            };
            return result;
          });
        },
        put: function(key, value) {
          cache.put(key, value);
        }
      };
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="test">

<head>
  <title>Loading all templates in one file...</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-include="'/one'">Not working...</div>
  <div ng-include="'/two'">Not working...</div>
</body>

</html>
```

- What has changed in version 1.7 which causes the problem?
- How can I fix it?
- Is there a better alternative?

Comment: I rewrote the codepen so it uses components instead of ng-include. Same result... 1.6.1 works fine, 1.7 and 1.8 not working... :(

Comment: Your snippet currently throws errors with 1.6.1, can you fix those and explain what you see with 1.6 that you don't see with 1.7?